# SQLite SELECT statement where column equals zero

Tags: sqlite

I'm preety new to SQLite.
I have a preety basic question.. Why can't I select rows where specific column equals zero?

The is_unwanted column is type `TINYINT` (which I see in SQLite basically means `INTEGER`)

So, I have only one record in the database (for testing).
When I try

```
SELECT is_unwanted FROM 'urls'
```

I get a result of "**0**" (**zero**), which is fine because that column contains the actual number **0**.

I tried =>

```
SELECT * FROM 'urls' WHERE is_unwanted = 0
```

And got NO result, but

```
SELECT * FROM 'urls' WHERE is_unwanted <> 0
```

gives me result.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Just for kicks try `SELECT * FROM urls WHERE is_unwanted IS NULL` and see if that returns anything.

Comment: @themanatuf just tried it, no results... but the column actually contains the number 0..

Comment: in the first SQL you have single quotes around the table name `'urls'` but you don't have that in the 2nd/3rd queries.  Have you tried adding those?

Comment: @bluefeet sorry it's a typo in the question.. that's not the problem

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but does changing `TINYINT` to `BOOLEAN` make a difference within your application?

Comment: @Andrej have you tried single quotes around your zeros in the `WHERE` clause? `is_unwanted = '0'`

Comment: Ok, forget my last question, is it possible to provide the `.schema` for the table in question?

Comment: @themanatuf yes, no difference.. I even tried INTEGER, but it's no use because it all comes back to INTEGER according to http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @bluefeet yes I tried that too.. hm, is it possible to tell me how to get the schema out of the sqlite :) I'm using SQLite admionistrator to check my queries..

Answer (score 2):

Try running

```
select '{' || is_unwanted || '}' from urls
```

to see if the value in the database is really a string containing spaces.

SQLite is a dynamically typed database; when you specify `TINYINT` is is a hint (SQLite uses the term "affinity") for the column. You can use

```
 select is_unwanted, typeof(is_unwanted) from urls
```

to see the values with their types.

Comment: this is what i got back as a result - {}

Comment: Then there is an empty sting or NUL in the string (blob).

Comment: I tried the second statement, it gave me 2 columns.. first one containing the number "0", and the seconds one containing the word "numeric"

Comment: Ok so it seems like that field has a 0x30 value which is a "0" in ASCII. Try querying for 0x30 (decimal 48).

Comment: Try: `SELECT * FROM urls WHERE is_unwanted = 48`

Comment: Numeric means is it a REAL, not an integer. But SQLite3 prints this as "real" not "numeric" -- what version of SQLite are you running?

Comment: thanks for all your help people.. turns out the value wasn't saved to DB as 0, but as empty string... which was confusin becouse the typeof() command stated it was a zero numeric.. anyway, solved now.. thanks once again!

Comment: I think you should try:
```SELECT * FROM urls WHERE is_unwanted = ''```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT * FROM urls WHERE coalesce(is_unwanted,'') = ''
```